# Difference between Ubuntu Server 20.04 Focal Fossa VS 20.04.2.0 LTS VS WSL2

Tags: server, 20.04, virtualbox

What is the difference between the Server Edition, Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS and WSL2?

What is Server Edition? Is it another VM that slows you down or does it offer any better features than Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS? Why is it called "Server"?
Should I switch over from WSL2 to Server Edition?

PS: If you are a bit confused about the versions I am referring to, here are the download links: 
[Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
[Ubuntu Server 20.04 Focal Fossa](https://www.osboxes.org/ubuntu-server/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu is a distribution of a Linux-based Computer Operating System.

Ubuntu 20.04 is the April 2020 (20.04) release of Ubuntu. Ubuntu 20.04.2 is the second major upgrade of 20.04, released in January 2021. 20.04.3 will be released in July 2021.

Ubuntu 20.04 comes in Desktop and Server editions, for computers with a display and keyboard (Desktop) and without a display and keyboard (Server). Both are simply collections of software packages. You can easily convert one edition into the other by changing software packages.

WSL and WSL2 are Windows applications that translate Ubuntu commands into Windows commands for processing by the Windows kernel. If you use a VM or install on bare metal, you don't need WSL/WSL2.

Comment: That was a really solid answer ! So this means that if I want to stick with the WSL2, I can install all the features of the Server Edition? That is because I don't want any GUI , I just need the terminal of the Server edition. As I far as I can tell by your answer this is perfectly fine, right?